# Interpret input with keypress for command line in python

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I want to build a command line in python to send TCL commands via remote control to a server. So far i get my commands from the python `input` function. Now i want add the possibility to access previous commands by a keypress.

```
import artistlib as a

list = ["SUCCESS", "RESULT", "STDOUT"]
commands = []

rc = a.Junction()

com = ""

c = 0

while com != "exit":
    com = input("Command: ")
    
    ver = a.Junction.send(rc, com, "*")

    for i in list:
        typ = a.Junction.pick(rc, ver, i)
        if "IMAGE" in ver and not "{}" in typ:
            name = input("Save Image as: ")
            a.Junction.image(rc, name)
            print("Image saved as ", name)
            
        if not "{}" in typ:
            if not "not found" in typ:
                print(typ)
            else:
                c += 1
        else:
            c += 1

    if c >= 3 and not "BASE64" in ver:
        print(ver)

    c = 0

else:
    exit()
```

How can i implement this function to my code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using rlwrap

One easy solution in Unix-like shells, might be to just invoke your script with [`rlwrap`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) which can easily provide the effect you want without the need to fuss with implementing this in Python. e.g.,

```bash
rlwrap python3 myscript.py
```

You may have to install `rlwrap` (e.g., `apt install -y rlwrap` on debian/ubuntu distributions)

### Using prompt-toolkit in Python

If you want to integrate this functionality using Python code exclusively, you might consider using [the history functionality from `prompt-toolkit`](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/asking_for_input.html#history) which helps you do the same thing within the `prompt-toolkit` framework. (you'll need to install prompt-toolkit -- `pip install prompt-toolkit`)

In this approach, you just need to create a `PromptSession` object (`session`) from prompt-toolkit and replace `input` with `session.prompt`

```py
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
session = PromptSession()

# ...

while com != "exit":
    com = session.prompt("Command: ")
    # ...
```

This will let you recall previous inputs in the same session. If you want the ability to recall all previous commands, even across restarts/reboots etc. you can save the history to a file.

```py
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
from prompt_toolkit.history import FileHistory

session = PromptSession(history=FileHistory('~/.myhistory'))
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach to solve the problem and it works. But can i run the code in the IDLE as well or only by using cmd?

Comment: @daveidix I'm not sure about IDLE because I don't use that tool. Some script runners in some IDEs may not allow for interactive prompts. In my own testing, the code using prompt-toolkit does run both in cmd as well as my regular IDE (PyCharm). If my answer helps you with your original question, please consider voting/accepting it. If you have a different question (like how to make it work in IDLE), consider posting it as a separate question instead.